# How to create multiple models from a single endpoint w/ Django RF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, model

I want to have an single endpoint that accepts a POST request and creates an  "Order" that can be one of two types. The User should be able to submit an order (of either type) as JSON, and create a new Order.

Behind the scenes, two models are created. One "Base Order" Model that describes some common characteristics, and one "Type A Order" or "Type B Order" that describes the characteristics specific to that order. The actual order types and their fields will be vastly more complicated so here are just described as A and B with a few charFields.

The general idea though is that the same endpoint is used to create two models, a `BaseOrder` model, and a model of a type determined by the `order_type` field submitted.

I think the conditional part of this (which order to make) should not be too difficult. But **I'm unsure how to create two separate models from the same endpoint, even if it was always of the same type.**

Models:

```
class BaseOrder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=False)

    class OrderType(models.TextChoices):
        TYPEA = "A", "Placeholder A"
        TYPEB = "B", "Placeholder B"

    order_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        verbose_name="Order Type",
        choices=OrderType.choices,
    )

class TypeAOrder(models.Model):
    a_field1 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    a_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    a_field3 = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class TypeBOrder(models.Model):
    b_field1 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    b_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

a POST request to the /order endpoint that contains a Type A order might look like this:

```
{
  "name": "test order",
  "timestamp": "2022-08-01T12:32:10Z",
  "ordertype": "A"
  "a_field1": "important"
  "a_field2": "data"
  "a_field3": "something"
},
```

And doing that would create TWO separate models. The `BaseOrder` Model and the `TypeAOrder` Model.

I found [this library](https://github.com/MattBroach/DjangoRestMultipleModels) that seems to be able to do this for combining models in a GET request, but does not seem to be for creating models. I'm assuming it's possible...

Answer (score 0):

Use the if/else condition within your view

1. Always create the base model
2. check the ordertype in if/else condition and create the sub model accordingly.
3. 

Also, make one-to-one relations b/w your Base model and sub-models.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using django-rest-framework for REST API, you can achieve that via something like this.

1. Serializer to validate Type A & B  model data.

```py
class TypeASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TypeAOrder
        fields = ['a_field1', 'a_field2', 'a_field3']

class TypeBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TypeBOrder
        fields = ['b_field1', 'b_field2']
```

2. BaseOrder Serializer with custom logic

```py
class BaseOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type_a_order = TypeASerializer(required=False)
    type_b_order = TypeBSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = BaseOrder
        fields = ['name', 'timestamp', 'order_type', 'type_a_order', 'type_b_order']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order_type = validated_data.pop('order_type')
        type_a_data = validated_data.pop('type_a_order', {})
        type_b_data = validated_data.pop('type_b_order', {})
        base_order = BaseOrder.objects.create(order_type=order_type, **validated_data)

        if order_type == BaseOrder.OrderType.TYPEA:
            TypeAOrder.objects.create(base_order=base_order, **type_a_data)
        elif order_type == BaseOrder.OrderType.TYPEB:
            TypeBOrder.objects.create(base_order=base_order, **type_b_data)

        return base_order
```

3. Define view which will use base order serializer

`CreateAPIView` will handle `def create(....)` part.

```py
class OrderView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = BaseOrder.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BaseOrderSerializer
```

4. Register APIView

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import OrderView

urlpatterns = [
    path('order/', OrderView.as_view(), name='create_order'),
]
```

5. Add test case

```py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime
import pytz


class OrderViewTestCase(APITestCase):
    def test_create_order_type_a(self):
        url = reverse('create_order')
        data = {
            "name": "test order",
            "timestamp": "2022-08-01T12:32:10Z",
            "order_type": "A",
            "type_a_order": {
                "a_field1": "important",
                "a_field2": "data",
                "a_field3": "something"
            }
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['name'], data['name'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['timestamp'], data['timestamp'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['order_type'], data['order_type'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['type_a_order']['a_field1'], data['type_a_order']['a_field1'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['type_a_order']['a_field2'], data['type_a_order']['a_field2'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['type_a_order']['a_field3'], data['type_a_order']['a_field3'])

    def test_create_order_type_b(self):
        url = reverse('create_order')
        data = {
            "name": "test order",
            "timestamp": "2022-08-01T12:32:10Z",
            "order_type": "B",
            "type_b_order": {
                "b_field1": "important",
                "b_field2": "data"
            }
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['name'], data['name'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['timestamp'], data['timestamp'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['order_type'], data['order_type'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['type_b_order']['b_field1'], data['type_b_order']['b_field1'])
        self.assertEqual(response.data['type_b_order']['b_field2'], data['type_b_order']['b_field2'])

    def test_create_order_invalid_payload(self):
        url = reverse('create_order')
        data = {
            "name": "test order",
            "timestamp": "2022-08-01T12:32:10Z",
            "order_type": "C",  # Invalid order type
            "type_b_order": {
                "b_field1": "important",
                "b_field2": "data"
            }
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

For more ref

- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/
- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to implement such. But, a simple example using [`ModelSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) and [`APIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views):

serializers.py

```py
class BaseOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.BaseOrder
        fields = ['name', 'timestamp', 'order_type']


class TypeAOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TypeAOrder
        fields = ['a_field1', 'a_field2', 'a_field3']


class TypeBOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TypeBOrder
        fields = ['b_field1', 'b_field2']
```

views.py

```py
class OrderAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        base_order = BaseOrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        base_order.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if base_order.validated_data['order_type'] == 'A':
            serializer = TypeAOrderSerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()

        elif base_order.validated_data['order_type'] == 'B':
            serializer = TypeBOrderSerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()

        base_order.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```